# Datatables.net ScrollX | Header and Data column width issues

Tags: jquery, css, scroll, datatables

I'm trying to create wrapper for datatables.net table component, which create and enable features datatables based on classes defined in table.

```
$('table.data-table').each(function() { 
    var props = {};
    if ($(this).hasClass('select') && $(this).hasClass('multi'))
        props.select = 'multi';
    else if ($(this).hasClass('select')
        props.select = 'single';
    if ($(this).hasClass('long-table')
        props.scrollX = true;
    ...
    ...
    ...
    $(this).DataTable(props);
});
```

Like you see above based on classes defined in table DataTable's features enabled for all HTML tables.

Test Case 1: Table should fill it's container.

Test case 2: Scrolling should not create misalignment.

Here my issues is, If I set `scrollX: true` Testcase 1 fails and Test case 2 success.[image]

If I ignore `scrollX: true` Testcase 1 success and Test case 2 fails. [image]
What will be possible solution to make both text cases success. I've already tried to set `scrollX: '100%'` and nothing got good results.

I don't wish to go with solution stating add `long-grid` class only to second grid and it automatically ignores `scrollX:true` on first grid. Because we know how many number of columns are there in table but not the length of string present in data and the screen size where the page rendered, this is for responsive application.

Any solution or CSS hacks are welcome.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Forget about scrollX, use the solution proposed on this question:

[Header columns misaligned with DataTable when scrollX is enabled](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897030/header-columns-misaligned-with-datatable-when-scrollx-is-enabled)

```
$('#DataTableID').DataTable({
  //"scrollX": true,            
  "initComplete": function (settings, json) {  
    $("#DataTableID").wrap("<div style='overflow:auto; width:100%;position:relative;'></div>");            
  },
});
```

Comment: I was misguided with `scrollX": true` and `columns.adjust()` recommendations through out the datatables forum and nothing worked for me. Only this solution works for me perfectly.

Comment: To make custom column width work, try `autoWidth: false` option.  [Column width not working](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44066200/8140473)

Answer (score 4):

I dont know about misalignment, but using `scrollX: true` makes the table not fill its container. To avoid this, set `style="width:100%"` in your `table`
[Datatables Flexible table width](https://datatables.net/examples/basic_init/flexible_width.html)

Another solution is wrapping your *.table* in *.table-responsive*
[Bootstrap Responsive tables](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/css/#tables-responsive)

I hope this helps someone.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem, I was getting json data but the user could also upload others. And at this moment I had a problem that after the user requested new data, the width of the table header and the width of the table body became different. I solved this problem by removing (scrollX: true) and leaving (scrollY : "200px") - I needed a fixed height. It was all in a wrapper and that's why it worked for me

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this issue, and came up with the perfect solution.

The solution is to set scrollX to true, but only for viewport widths that are insufficient to display all of the columns.  You must destroy and recreate the table at the breakpoint to do this.  You will absolutely get the desired behavior when you do this!  The breakpoint will depend upon your table, in the example below it was 576.

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var toggleScroll = function () {

        var ww = document.body.clientWidth;
 
        const dtOpts = {
            "scrollX": (ww < 576),
            order: [],
            destroy: true
        }
        new DataTable('#myTable', dtOpts);

    };

    // Make Changes when the window is resized
    $(window).resize(function () {
        toggleScroll();
    });

    // Fire when the page first loads
    toggleScroll();
});
```